# Find basis of orthogonal complement of space W

Tags: vector-spaces, orthogonality

I am supposed to find a basis of orthogonal complement of space W = $[(1,1,0,1),(0,1,0,1), (0,0,0,1)]$ .

I have already found an orthogonal basis of W, which is $[(1,1,0,1), (-2/3,1/3,0,1/3) (0,-1/2,0,1/2)]$

How would I find the basis of orthogonal complement?

I don't know how to begin, however my textbook says, it is supposed to be an easy problem, basically without any calculations. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The orthogonal completement of $W$ is the set of all vectors that are each orthogonal to all of the vectors in $W$.

The basis of the orthogonal complement, then, is a set of vectors such that all of the vectors in the orthogonal complement can be written as a linear combination of these vectors.

Let’s first take a simpler example in $\mathbb{R}^3$. If we have a subspace with basis $\{(1,0,0),(0,1,0)\}$ then this is a two-dimensional subspace—it describes a plane in 3D. It should be fairly obvious that there can only be one more dimension within which we can have vectors that are orthogonal to *all* of the vectors in our subspace, and therefore the basis will have only one vector. Can you come up with a single vector that is perpendicular to *all* the vectors in our subspace? $(0,0,1)$ works, and this is indeed the basis of the orthogonal complement.

Can you answer your question now?

Comment: How do I know that (0,0,1) is perpendicular to all the vectors in the subspace?

Comment: Take the dot product of $(0,0,1)$ with each vector in the subspace and see that it is always zero. I’m assuming that’s how you are defining orthogonality in this example.

Comment: Thanks, I understand now. And how do I know that the orthogonal complement of a 3-Dim subspace of R4 is 1-dimensional?

Comment: $\mathbb{R}^4$ has four basis vectors. So if we have a 3-dimensional subspace of this then it must have three basis vectors. Now assume we have more than one basis vector, say two vectors, in the basis of the orthogonal complement. Then, by the definition of a basis, these vectors are linearly independent. But then they can’t be linearly independent with the vectors in our 3-dimensional subspace, because then we would have a basis of $3+2 = 5$ vectors for $\mathbb{R}^4$, which is impossible. The argument extends for any number of basis vectors greater than $4-3$.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the vector space $W$ is a 3-dim.  subspace of ${\Bbb R}^4$ and so the orthogonal complement $W^\perp$ is 1-dimensional. Looking at the basis of $W$, it is clear that $W^\perp$ is generated by $(0,0,1,0)$.

Comment: Could you please explain why is it clear that it's generated by $(0,0,1,0)$?

Comment: Have a look at the 3rd coordinate of the basis vectors of $W$.

Comment: And how do I know that the orthogonal complement of a 3-Dim subspace of R4 is 1-dimensional?

Comment: $\dim {\Bbb R}^n = \dim W+ \dim W^\perp$.